# Explain the typecasting in qsort() function in c?

Tags: c, qsort

1)In this piece of code `pLhs` and `pRhs` are pointing to some random memory location then how the content of this random memory location is being copied to location to which LHS is pointing??

2)explain comparator function used in `qsort()` in C??

```
int comparator(const void *pLhs, const void *pRhs)
{

    int *lhs = (int *)pLhs;

    int *rhs = (int *)pRhs;
 

    return *lhs > *rhs;
}
```

This piece of code is form this program of sum of subset

https://www-geeksforgeeks-org.cdn.ampproject.org/v/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/subset-sum-backtracking-4/amp/?amp_js_v=a6&amp_gsa=1&usqp=mq331AQHKAFQArABIA%3D%3D#aoh=16210898076202&referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com&amp_tf=From%20%251%24s&ampshare=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.geeksforgeeks.org%2Fsubset-sum-backtracking-4%2F

Comment: All the compare function does is compare the two values.  The copying takes place in the calling function, based on the specified size of the elements.  In your case, you're sorting an array of `int` values, so the compare function casts the two pointers to the correct type, then loads and compares the values they point to.

Comment: I think the best explanation for the cast is that it is extraneous cruft.  You do not need to cast an assignment from `void *`.

Comment: GFG is full of poor quality examples and tutorials, btw. Like this one. I wouldn't use it as a learning resource.

Comment: (1) The premise of your question is entirely wrong. `pLHS` and `pRHS` are anything but "random;" they're pointers to elements of the array that you're trying to sort. (2) You apparently haven't even read `man qsort`. You should do that; it explains a lot.

Answer (score 2):

`qsort` is written so that it can sort any type of data. Much of sorting is moving items around in memory, and this can be accomplished just by moving the bytes that represent the data: You do not need to know the meaning of the bytes in two array elements to exchange them, you just need to know where they are and how many bytes are in each of them. So `qsort` can accept a `void *` that parts to the start of the array and a `size_t` that tells it how many bytes are in each element, and it does not care what the original type of the `void *` is.

However, `qsort` cannot decide which of two elements in the sort order is earlier based on the bytes alone. It could sort all the array elements purely by the binary values of the bits in their bytes, but somebody might want to sort an array in reverse order or sort strings by alphabetical order ignoring case or sort by floating-point interpretation. Each of these is a different ordering than just going by the binary values. So `qsort` needs a helper routine. That is the comparison routine that is passed to it.

Since `qsort` is only given a `void *`, it does not know what the original type of the array elements is, so it cannot pass that type to the comparison routine. The comparison routine must convert the `void *` to the correct type. Each comparison routine is customized for the type of the elements it compares. The pointers it are passed do not point to random addresses; they point to elements in the array being sorted.

Given the function declaration `int comparator(const void *pLhs, const void *pRhs)`, the assignment `int *lhs = (int *) pLhs;` converts the `void *` parameter `pLhs` to an `int *` variable `lhs`. Then `*lhs` can be used as an `int`, and so can `rhs`.

There are three errors or shortcomings in the sample code you show. First, the comparison routine is passed a `const void *`. It is expected not to change the values that are pointed to. So it ought to convert the pointers to `const int *`, not `int *`.

Second, the cast is unnecessary in C. Simply doing `const int *lhs = pLhs;` will work. The compiler will automatically convert the `const void *` to `const int *` when initializing `lhs`. (In C++, such a cast may be necessary.) In C, such casts are discouraged where they are not necessary because, in some situations, they can conceal bugs by evading warning messages the compiler would produce if the cast were not present. In fact, that has happened here. With the cast, Apple Clang 11 issues no warning for the initialization. Without the cast, the compiler warns that the initialization discards the `const` qualifier.

Third, `return *lhs > *rhs;` is insufficient. The `qsort` comparison should return a negative value if the left parameter should be sorted before the right, zero if they are the same as far as the sort order is concerned, and a positive value if the left parameter should be sorted after the right. So correct code for ascending order could be:

```
return *lhs < *rhs ? -1 : *lhs == *rhs ? 0 : +1;
```

For descending order, it could be:

```
return *lhs > *rhs ? -1 : *lhs == *rhs ? 0 : +1;
```

If you are not yet comfortable with the conditional operator, you can use:

```
if (*lhs > *rhs)
    return -1;
else if (*lhs == *rhs)
    return  0;
else
    return +1;
```

Comment: in this  const int *lhs = pLhs; how pointer lhs is pointing to a value which is pointed by the plhs.i think it should be.                                                        const int *lhs;                                                                        
lhs=(int*)plhs;  Doess the address to which plhs is pointing get passed to lhs while typecasting.or it's a syntax for typecasting const int *lhs=plhs.

Comment: @Physicsislove: `const int *lhs = pLhs;` says “Define `lhs` to be a `const int *` and initialize it with the value of `pLhs`. An initialization in a declaration initializes the thing being declared, `lhs`, not the thing it points to, `*lhs`. In an assignment, `*lhs = value;` would set the things `lhs` points to, `*lhs` to the value, because `*` is part of an expression, so `*lhs` is the operand on the left side of the `=`. In a declaration, `*` is part of a declarator telling us what the type is. It does not form an expression. `const int *lhs = pLhs;` correctly initializes the pointer `lhs`.

Comment: can u pls explain with the help of an example..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=+how+inner+if+condition+is+working+when+the+outer+if+condition+is+false+for+i%3D1+and+v%3D4.+

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for a qsort compare function. I aligned the top to show the matching of types.

```
int
cmp_float(void const *v1, 
          void const *v2 )
{
        double const *d1 = v1,
                     *d2 = v2;

    if (*d1 == *d2)
        return 0;
    else
        return *d1 > *d2 ? 1 : -1;
}
```

I had first a second "0" instead of "-1" for the third case...it worked anyway.

---

E.P.'s A says it all. Except maybe: IF you go for a slap-dash cast, then do it like:

`double d1 = *(double *)v1;`

so you can use `d1` and `d2` without stars afterwards. In my above version I would need a second assigment (like `double D1 = *d1`). A dereference after the implicit conversion.

Put at the right spot a `*` looks nice. Casts are ugly in general.

---

> random memory location

It is not random, it corresponds to two of the array elements being qsorted.

The caller who feeds qsort() with the array (pointer, element size, n elements) and the compare function name has to know what he is sorting: can be array of chars or array of large structs. Or (ideally) an array of pointers.

With chars there might be some overhead. Why pass around two long addresses to compare two bytes?

With bigger structs or (sub)arrays the amount of shuffling becomes the problem.

Comment: @eric postpischil can u plz explain this                                 .1. how inner if condition is working when the outer if condition is false for i=1 and v=4.

if (i == V) {
        // if coloring is safe
        if (isSafe(graph, color)) {
            // Print the solution
            printSolution(color);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    } 
refer this program for complete code

https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/AfK9JFN2aD

2 can someone plz explain how code is working?how each node is assigned a new colour. https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/AfK9JFN2aD